# Two part question on selected users being added correctly to a multidimensional array in react native

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, multidimensional-array

I am trying to figure out how I can get the selected users to be added to a multidimensional array at different times. The way my code works now, it takes the selected users from the CustomerQue page and it adds them to the Tables page. The consumer then adds a table number and then hits set, and that adds the user to the table number. The table is the array. But when I go back and try to add/select more users to add to a different table. It adds the table and the users all together.

Here is my code from CustomerQue...

```js
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            rlocationcode: '',
            dataSource: [],
            selectedUsers: [],
        };
    }
    
handleTouchItem2 = async (item) => {
        try {
            let users = this.state.dataSource;
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify(users));
            this.props.navigation.navigate("Tables", {
                cust_ID: item,
                otherParam: '101',
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('There is no one checked in', error.message);
        }
    }
    
_didSelectUsers = (item) => {
        let selectedUsers1 = this.state.selectedUsers;
        let isItemSelected = selectedUsers1.filter(item => {
            return item.includes(item);
        }).length > 20
            ? true : false;

        if (isItemSelected) {
            const index = selectedUsers1.findIndex(
                obj => obj.item === selectedUsers1
            );
            selectedUsers1.splice(index, 1);
        } else {
            selectedUsers1.push(item);
        }
        this.setState({ selectedUsers1 });
        console.log(selectedUsers1)
    }
```

Here is my code for the Tables Page....

```js
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.array = [],
        this.party = [],
        this.state = {
            arrayHolder: [],
            party: [],
            disabled: true,
            textInput_Holder: '',
            selectedIndex: 2,
        }
        this.updateIndex = this.updateIndex.bind(this)
    }

_addTable = (index) => {
        if (index === 0) {
            this.array.push({Table : this.state.textInput_Holder});
            for (var i = 0; i < this.array.length; i++) {
                this.setState({ arrayHolder: [...this.array] });
                console.log(this.array); 
            }
        }
    }
    
_setTable2 = async (index) => {
        if (index === 1) {
            const  { navigation } = this.props;
            const cust = navigation.getParam('cust_ID', 'No-User');
            const other_param = navigation.getParam('otherParam', 'No-User');

            const cust1 = JSON.stringify(cust);
            const cust2 = cust1.replace(/[\])}[{(]/g, '');
            const cust3 = cust2.replace(/[""]/g, '');
            
            try {
                await AsyncStorage.setItem('cust3', cust3)
                let Tab = [this.array];
                let TAC = Tab.concat([cust3]);
                this.state.party.push([cust3]);
                for (var i = 0; i < this.state.party.length; i++) {
                    this.setState({ party: [...this.state.party]})
                    console.log(this.state.party.join('\r\n'));
                    return this.state.party.join('\r\n');
                }
                
            } catch(error) {
                console.log('There is a problem', error.message);
            }
        }
            
    }
    
_openTable = async () => {
        try {
            const partyGroup = await AsyncStorage.getItem('cust3');
            this.props.navigation.navigate('ViewParty', {
                TAC1: partyGroup,
                otherParam: '101',
            });
        } catch(error) {
            console.log('No Table', error.message)
        }
     }
```

I have tried to removeItem from AsyncStorage and it removes everything even the items I had already added to the array. I tried to splice the selectedUsers and it does that same thing. It removes everything and when i try to selected new users, it adds that ones that I just removed back to the selected users.

What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Try react-native hooks. Or also you can try state management such as redux mobx to handle data throughout your app life cycle.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking time out to comment, I will look into both and let you know which one works for me.